# How do I handle storing coins for an app that will use an ETH token?

Tags: wallets, addresses

Im making a website thats going to use a custom token. Im new to developing using eth tokens/coins.

How do I store and access the users tokens?

What Im wondering is do I create additional addresses in my own local wallet (geth) for each user or should they come to the site already having their own wallets from elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

This is a potentially far-reaching subject because any combination of contracts, clients and servers is possible, each with their own implementation details.

I can provide an introductory conceptual starting point for your thinking using the Minimum Viable Token contract here: https://www.ethereum.org/token

The Smart Contract is designed to track balances for users. In summary, it's a bank. Important thing to realize is `msg.sender` is always the ethereum address that called the function. This is the user's Ethereum address.

This line:

```
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
```

sets up a namespace using addresses as keys and storing unsigned integers called `balanceOf`. `public` means there is a read-only getter function that will require one argument (the `address`) and return a `uint256`. Anyone can use that to inquire about anyone's balance.

There's also a function `transfer()`.

Notice that it uses `msg.sender` to find values stored in `balanceOf`. In particular, this line is illustrative:

```
balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
```

The balance of the `msg.sender` is reduced by the `_value` to transfer.

Implicitly, users can only send from their own accounts. A browser-based user interface could tell the user's Ethereum node to send a transaction to the contract. The contract would check for sufficient funds, then move the funds (`_value`) from the user to the `_to` address (passed in). The end.

A web server isn't needed in the simple case above. In many cases, a web server may be *interested*. Ethereum has a facility to inform a web server. An event emitter can be added to the contract. A server can have its own Ethereum node and listen for important events.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's helpful, but doesn't quite answer the question. What I'm wondering I guess is how do exchanges provide you with a temporary wallet while you trade? I want to do something like that. Have a temporary wallet that works in the site but you can put your funds back in your permanent wallet when you're done.

Comment: There's an interface standard called ERC20 that might be helpful. ERC20 helps move coins to/from exchanges. Same interface might be useful for moving funds to/from site, if that's necessary. https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens

Comment: Ok, I figured out what it is im trying to ask about, its how to create and use hot wallets or other wallets that dont need private keys to send and receive funds.